# Why Deployment Assembly does not show mapping of WebContent/WEB-INF/lib from Eclipse project folder to application server folder?

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee

By default Eclipse (Dynamic Web Project, Eclipse for Java EE, 4.9.0 version) has/shows the following configuration

[image]

I can manually add the following line:

[image]

*But it seems that this mapping already works by default and I do not need to manually add it.*

I wonder why mapping of `WebContent/WEB-INF/lib` (in package explorer) into `/WEB-INF/lib` (on server) is not shown in `Deployment Assembly` tab if it is anyway present there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parent folder, `WebContent`, is already mapped. All of its contents are deployed, including what's in the `WEB-INF` folder it contains.